# How to classify this schema?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-attribute-value

I have such schema:
[image]

The essence of this scheme is in organization of the entry point for all products of some company, that gives some flexibility.

How it works:

1. We create a list of tables in the table "tables" (where `name` is the name of the table in database, `pk_name` is the name of the primary key of this table)
2. We create a list of products in "products" (where `table_id` is the table identifier in "tables", `pk_value` is the value of the primary key)
3. Also, we create tables like "some_product", "another_product", etc. They contain different fields for a specific product

The questions are:

1. How such schemes are called? For example, EAV is also designed for
   database flexibility, but in EAV columns are stored as records in
   the database.
2. Therefore, I can not understand is it advisable to compare this scheme with EAV or not?
3. What analogies of this schema are there, to understand what is better to use?
4. What are disadvantages of this schema?

I'm novice in DB, so I hope that my questions are not stupid.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you have shown both `some_product` and `another_product` tables have the same attributes and types. It would be better to have one product table in that case. If different attributes apply to different types of product in different tables then that is an example of *subtyping*.

Attributes that are common to all products would go in the common `products` table (the *supertype* table). I would expect to see a product type attribute in that table to differentiate the various types of product.

The `tables` table is unnecessary. All DBMSs provide access to the metadata about tables and primary keys so there is no reason to capture that in your own table.